# Can i upload multiple images for testing after deploying an object detection model on Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

Under the "DEPLOY AND TEST" section of vertex ai after training an AutoML model, I only have the option of uploading one image at a time. I have an image that I have split into multiple images because i wanted to reduce the size of the image. Now is there a way using APIs that I can automate the process of uploading images to vertex ai for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have deployed your model, Vertex AI has created one REST API endpoint that you can use to perform manual testing.

So to perform testing, you just need to interact with this endpoint (using Vertex AI SDK). There is a sample on the documentation - you can check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-predict-image-object-detection-sample).